# Dont open item list when focus Autocomplate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
<AutoComplete
  fullWidth={true}
  name='claimTypeName'
  dataSourceConfig={{ text: 'name', value: 'id' }}
  dataSource={::this.getClaimTypesList()}
  onNewRequest={::this.onClaimTypeItemClick}
  openOnFocus={true}
/>

getClaimTypesList() {
  const { types } = this.props;

  return [
    { name: 'test 1', id: 80439850348504},
    { name: 'test 3', id: 435345345},
  ];

  return types.map(({ name, id }) => {
    return { name, id };
  });
}
```

But when I click(focus) AutoComplete element list dont show, what's wrong ?

If I add `searchText`

```
<AutoComplete
  fullWidth={true}
  name='claimTypeName'
  dataSourceConfig={{ text: 'name', value: 'id' }}
  dataSource={::this.getClaimTypesList()}
  onNewRequest={::this.onClaimTypeItemClick}
  onUpdateInput={::this.handleClaimTypeName}
  openOnFocus={true}
  searchText={this.state.claimTypeName ? this.state.claimTypeName : ' '}
/>

handleClaimTypeName(e) {
        const claimTypeName = e.target.value;

        this.setState({
            claimTypeName
        });
    }
```

If I focus before type anything list show, but if I start type AutoComplete dont search and have error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at WrappedComponent.handleClaimTypeName (ClaimCreate.js:146)
    at AutoComplete.<anonymous> (AutoComplete.js:209)
    at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (CallbackQueue.js:76)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.close (ReactUpdates.js:59)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:206)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:153)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.perform (ReactUpdates.js:89)
    at Object.flushBatchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:172)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:206)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:153)
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `e.target` it seems target is `undefined`. As I see it here: http://hackingbeauty.com/create-a-reactjs-component-part1/ `e` is already the `inptValue` not an `event`.

Comment: thanks, not noticed that is not onChange function

Comment: got the solution or still facing the issue ?

Comment: yes, but now before type in input exist one space symbol, and have to remove whitespace before typing

Comment: I assume this is the problem `searchText={this.state.claimTypeName ? this.state.claimTypeName : ' '}` , instead of `' '` do `''` without a space.

Comment: @ppasler if use '' instead ' ', autocomplate don't show list on focus

Comment: Have you tried this: `searchText={this.state.claimTypeName}` ?

Comment: @ppasler yes, if use `' '` autocomplate show list without typing, just focus, if use `searchText={this.state.claimTypeName}` it's equal `''` and don't show list on focus, need type word to show list

Comment: I see, so you have to decide if you want the list on focus (but having the space) or having the list on typing but no space

Comment: Try `triggerUpdateOnFocus={true}` , here's an issue related to this: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/2969